# INSERT SELECT SQL from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables one table tbl_OrderLine with order ID and one tbl_Student with Student ID.

I want to select the OrderLineID from tbl_OrderLine and The StudentID From tbl_Student

This is what I have tried so far:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_StudentPurchaseFromUnibooks 
  (OrderLineID, StudentID )
SELECT tbl_OrderLine.OrderLineID, 
SELECT tbl_Student.StudentID 
 WHERE tbl_Student.LoggedIn ="Yes";
```

tbl_OrderLine:

```
OrderLineID     Price       Qty
1                 5          2
```

tbl_Student:

```
StudentID     Name    LoggedIn
1             Joe      Yes
```

tbl_StudentPurchaseFromUnibooks:

```
StudentPurchaseID    OrderLineID    StudentID    PurchaseDate
1                     1               1            09/12/2012
```

Also, does any one know a simple way of mimicking a login in Microsoft Access. As this is only dummy database for a Microsoft Access project security isn't an issue but I just would like to know a way of logging users in. At the moment i update their LoggedIn value to "Yes" if they are logged in but obviously this isn't efficient. If no one is able to help with this I will post as a seperate question later :) Thanks!

Comment: thank you for your reply, no there are not any fields in common i will add an example

Comment: have added the example, I originally thought that if the user is logged in then they will be charged and only one user will be logged in at a time (as it is a just a simple project database) however, if you know a more effective way I would appreciate your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to define your select as a join instead of two separate SQLs. I am not really sure how MS works, but something like this should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_StudentPurchaseFromUnibooks (OrderLineID,   StudentID )
SELECT tbl_OrderLineID.OrderLineID, tbl_Student.StudentID
from tbl_OrderLineId
left join tbl_Student on ???
WHERE tbl_Student.LoggedIn ="Yes";
```

I am not sure that your table should really be named `tbl_OrderLineID` and you would need to know your join condition.

Comment: thank you for your reply sorry about the table name that was a typo! What do you mean by join condition?

Comment: If you want to match rows from different tables, you need to tell the database which columns to match (join) from the respective rows. Check this site out to get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp